# How can I interpolate variables with out using a template?

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, express

I'm new to node / express ( coming from PHP ) and I'm tying to do something very simple that I would assume would be easier in Node.

For example, in PHP if I have an index.php file, I can just do.

`<php echo "$var">` to get a variable in my "index.php" file which consists of mostly HTML despite the extension.

**I know this does not exist** but why not something similar to

`<js-engine output "var">`

Here is the PHP equivalent.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <base href=<?php echo $dir_base;?> target="_blank">
    <head>
```

How can I achieve this same effect in a node environment with out using templates.  I don't need the complexity of a template and technically this is not a template it is not repeated.  Just a simple variable interpolated for use in my HTML. I tried this [tuts+ tut](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-express--net-33367) to no avail.  I'm starting to think this is the only way.

My file is mostly HTML and I'm just using the code below to send it.
I need to set the variable in the file itself.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(path_index_resolved);
});
```

Comment: Either you use templates or you combine the strings before you send it back to frontend...

Comment: How can I combine the strings "before I send it to the backend"?

Answer (score 0):

Without template you can combine the strings:

```
var myText = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
myText += '<html><base href="'+link+'"> target="_blank"><head>';
// and so on
res.send(myText);
```

However, I prefer either using templates or a frontend like angular2 with node.js... There are [templates in express](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) worthwhile to take a look on it.

Comment: I updated my question.  I have a file full of HTML and I just need to make a few part variables.  Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer, take a look into the templates documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot use Node.js like PHP. You need to pass your variables manually (serve html with interpolated values - HTML as string) or use some kind of template engine.

You can use for example [Pug](https://github.com/pugjs/pug), [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/), and [EJS](https://github.com/tj/ejs) if you'd choose template engine solution.